# Powershell, Sorting a collection by Regex Match count

Tags: regex, sorting, powershell

I am having trouble sorting a collection by the number of match each items of the collection.

Here is the line I am using :

```
"2\\aa","3\\\aaa","1\a" | Sort-Object {([regex]"a").Match($_).count} -Descending
```

Results:

```
2\\aa
3\\\aaa
1\a
```

I was expecting this :

```
3\\\aaa
2\\aa
1\a
```

What I actually want to do is a bit more complicated, I want to open a project visual studio .vbproj file, and sort all  element by their sub-directory count. My original script is as follow :

```
[regex]$regex = "\\"
$proj = [xml](get-content C:\project\project.vbproj)

$entries = $proj.GetElementsByTagName("Content")
$sortedEntries = $entries | Sort-Object {$regex.Match($_.Include).count} -    Descending
```

Comment: `Match` -> `Matches`

Comment: That's it !! Thank you it work.

Comment: @PetSerAl I think you can post your comment as an answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the property is `Matches`, not `Match`.